# Struggling to browse to Kibana 3

Tags: linux, apache, elasticsearch, kibana

Rookie getting my feet wet. Reasonably new to Linux, Apache, Elasticsearch and Kibana.

Running SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES) 11, and Elasticsearch 1.5.2, Apache (apache2).

Tried working with Kibana 4.0.2, found some bugs and weird issues, want to use Kibana 3.1.2 instead. I'm on a deadline.

What do I need to configure so that I can browse to the Kibana 3 instance? I have configured my kibana-3.1.2/config.js to point to my ES server, but am unsure of other changes, especially within Apache.

Any help would be great and I can offer any more details needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I run logstash, es and kibana4 and love it on debian 8. Im not sure of what you got feedimg to what but digital ocean is a great resource. Here is a nice walkthrough to help you figure out ejar you should do next depending on where you stand in your setup.https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-and-visualize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04

It also explains the ins and outs a littlite bit so you wont feel so new. Enjoy.